# I have a type error in powershell but the type is available in the documentation

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script in powershell and getting the following error:

```
Error Caught: Cannot bind parameter 'Type'.
Cannot convert value "TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group" to type "PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Enums.SiteType".
Error: "Unable to match the identifier name TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group to a valid enumerator name.
Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:   CommunicationSite, TeamSite"
```

The code itself:

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group
```

(There are other parameters I have omitted)

The documentation on https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/New-PnPSite.html
states that the type I am using should work (TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group) but I am given the 2 enumerators instead. Appreciate the help.

I changed to the enumerators CommunicationSite and TeamSite and they work but TeamSite does not have a Url parameter hence I don't want to use it.

Comment: Have you tried the command with the same parameters as "Example 11" in the docs - i.e. ```New-PnPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group -Title <some_title> -Url <some_url>```  - see  https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/New-PnPSite.html#example-11. Also, FWIW the same error was reported as an issue on GitHub here - https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/2529 (no replies, though)...

Comment: Yes I have, so I was able to fix it. It turns out my powershell version needed to be updated to 7 and above for the PnP module to work.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my powershell version needed to be updated to 7 and above for the PnP module to work. Now I don't have any errors when running my script.